# Как делаются маски для ввода номера телефона с выбором страны и т.д

Tags: html, css, валидация

Как делаются маски для ввода номера телефона с выбором страны и т.д.?
Есть ли какие-либо источники?

Comment: Вопрос ни о чем....  С таким количеством балов...)))  Смешно....

Answer (score 1):

Маску задавайте в обработчике события по нажатию на клавишу. Можно использовать регулярные выражения для сканирования инпута. Желательно в тултипе или HTML заставки показать пример правильного значения с учётом маски. Ошибки валидации можно отображать сразу же.